# Raw text "" must be wrapped in explicit text component

Tags: react-native

I am using a react native component listview to render nested items as follows:

```
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
            [
              {'main':'q', 'sub': 'y'}
            ],
            [
              {'main':'x', 'sub': 'f'},
              {'main':'c', 'sub': 'b'}
            ]
          ]),
        };
      }

      renderRow(rowData, section, row) {
        const total = this.state.dataSource.getRowCount();

        let rowView = rowData.map( x => {
          return <View> <Text>{x['main']}</Text> <Text>{x['sub']}</Text> </View>
        })
        return (
          <View>

            {rowView}
          </View>
        );
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ListView style={styles.listView}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this.renderRow}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
```

But I am getting following error:
Raw text "" must be wrapped in explicit text component.

I am unable to track where I am getting this error from.

[image]

Comment: Might it bethe space between `<View> <Text>` ?

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks a ton.That was the issue.

Comment: Quick fix!  format document with editors Code styling option, spaces between tags gets automatically removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let rowView = rowData.map( x => {
          return <View> <Text>{x['main']}</Text> <Text>{x['sub']}</Text> </View>
        })
```

Remove spaces between **View** And **Text** Components. Use tab and enter instead of space character.

```
let rowView = rowData.map( x => {
              return <View>
                         <Text>{x['main']}</Text>
                         <Text>{x['sub']}</Text>
                     </View>
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I used regex search & replace in entire file, and replacing `>(\s)+<Text` with `><Text` works.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly this issue arise due to space between `<View> <Text>` etc

A trick fix for this issue could be execute **Format Document** (I am using VScode (IDE), you can try with any IDE which have code styling capability). By Style fixing spaces between tags gets automatically removed.